# Full documentation about $args for register_rest_route?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

I'm currently setting up a WP REST API, and the tool is really impressive and the amount of possibilities vast. I would however really love it to have a full documentation listing all of the possible keys you can provide for $args when calling [register_rest_route](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/), just as you have it with [register_post_type](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/).

We're slowly building our own documentation with the gathered information across different pages since more than a week now, but wondered if there isn't a full documentation on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> full documentation listing all of the possible keys you can provide
> for $args when calling
> [register_rest_route](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/),
> just as you have it with
> [register_post_type](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/)

`register_rest_route()`, as of writing, doesn't have such a documentation; however, you can call [`$request->get_attributes()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_request/get_attributes/) inside of your endpoint callback to get the full (registration) options (including those not explicitly specified) for that specific endpoint.

- Excerpt from https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/requests/#attributes:

  > If we made a `GET` request to `my-namespace/v1/books`, and then we called `$request->get_attributes()` inside of our endpoint callback, we would be returned all of the registration options for the `my-namespace/v1/books` endpoint.

  > In the attributes we will get a response containing supported methods, options, whether to show this endpoint in the index, a list of registered arguments for the endpoint, and our registered callbacks.

So for example, the following registers a route containing 2 endpoints:

```php
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'my_plugin_register_rest_routes' );
function my_plugin_register_rest_routes() {
    register_rest_route( 'my-plugin/v1', 'foo', array(
        // Endpoint 1 - Get an item.
        array(
            'callback'            => 'my_plugin_rest_get_foo',
            'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
        ),

        // Endpoint 2 - Create an item.
        array(
            'methods'             => 'POST',
            'callback'            => 'my_plugin_rest_create_foo',
            'permission_callback' => 'my_plugin_rest_create_foo_permissions_check',
            'args'                => my_plugin_rest_create_foo_arguments(),
            'show_in_index'       => false,
        ),
    ) );
}

function my_plugin_rest_get_foo( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    return $request->get_attributes();
}

function my_plugin_rest_create_foo( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    return array( $request->get_attributes(), $request->get_params() );
}

function my_plugin_rest_create_foo_permissions_check() {
    return current_user_can( 'manage_options' );
}

function my_plugin_rest_create_foo_arguments() {
    $args = array();

    $args['title'] = array(
        'type'              => 'string',
        'required'          => true,
        'sanitize_callback' => 'my_plugin_title_arg_sanitize_callback',
    );

    $args['color'] = array(
        'type'     => 'string',
        'required' => true,
        'enum'     => array( 'red', 'green', 'blue' ),
    );

    return $args;
}

function my_plugin_title_arg_sanitize_callback( $value, WP_REST_Request $request, $param ) {
    return wp_filter_kses( $value ); // allows basic HTML; e.g. <b> is OK, but not <hr />
}
```

And here's what the endpoint callback returned in my case (WordPress v6.0):

- `GET my-plugin/v1/foo`

  ```
  Request via cURL:
  curl -X GET https://example.com/wp-json/my-plugin/v1/foo

  Sample response:
  {
      "methods": {
          "GET": true
      },
      "accept_json": false,
      "accept_raw": false,
      "show_in_index": true,
      "args": [],
      "callback": "my_plugin_rest_get_foo",
      "permission_callback": "__return_true"
  }
  ```
- `POST my-plugin/v1/foo`

  ```
  Request via cURL:
  curl --user "<username>:<application password>"
      -X POST https://example.com/wp-json/my-plugin/v1/foo
      -H "Content-Type: application/json"
      -d '{"title": "test with <b>HTML</b><hr /> yeah", "color": "blue"}'

  Sample response:
  [{
      "methods": {
          "POST": true
      },
      "accept_json": false,
      "accept_raw": false,
      "show_in_index": false,
      "args": {
          "title": {
              "type": "string",
              "required": true,
              "sanitize_callback": "my_plugin_title_arg_sanitize_callback"
          },
          "color": {
              "type": "string",
              "required": true,
              "enum": ["red", "green", "blue"]
          }
      },
      "callback": "my_plugin_rest_create_foo",
      "permission_callback": "my_plugin_rest_create_foo_permissions_check"
  }, {
      "title": "test with <b>HTML<\/b> yeah",
      "color": "blue"
  }]
  ```

So as you could see, each endpoint contains 7 top-level attributes, namely:

- `methods` — One or more HTTP methods allowed for the endpoint.
- `args` — Arguments for the endpoint.
- `callback` — The main callback function for responding to the request.
- `permission_callback` — A function which checks if the user can perform the action (reading, updating, etc.) before the real/main callback is called.

  **Note:** As of WordPress v5.5, if a `permission_callback` is not provided, the REST API will issue a `_doing_it_wrong` notice. So at bare minimum, an endpoint should *always* have both `callback` and `permission_callback`. And for REST API routes that are intended to be public, you can use `__return_true` as the permission callback.
- `show_in_index` — A boolean indicating whether the endpoint should be included in the route index, e.g. at `https://example.com/wp-json/my-plugin/v1` in my case.

  **Note:** You can omit your REST routes/endpoints from the index by using `'show_in_index' => false` when registering your REST routes. However, the routes themselves will still be accessible. But you can *use the permission callback to limit access* to your endpoints.
- `accept_json` and `accept_raw` — In [REST API v1](http://wp-api.org/guides/extending.html), (I believe) they were `WP_JSON_Server::ACCEPT_JSON` and `WP_JSON_Server::ACCEPT_RAW` respectively.

  But in REST API v2, those "accept_xxx" are `false` by default, so I don't know what these are for in REST API v2. Maybe they're defined just for back-compat?

And as for the *first four* attributes above, they're well-documented in the REST API handbook:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/